# Mirror Api For Glass(JAVA) gives 500 error code

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I am trying to run the quick start mirror api in java for glass development.When i am trying to run it from local host the oauth2callback fails giveing me a 500 error code messege

Log shows following messege in browser

Problem accessing /oauth2callback. Reason:

```
connect timed out
```

Caused by:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:79)
    at com.google.glassware.AuthServlet.doGet(AuthServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at com.google.glassware.ReauthFilter.doFilter(ReauthFilter.java:53)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at com.google.glassware.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

kindly help me on this.

Comment: 5XX class errors are out of your hands.  You'd have to talk to Google about why their API is suddenly broken.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use any tunneling software? it cannot directly access your localhost. use "ngrok" run and use the generated url in "MirrorClient.java" like

```
callbackUrl = "https://cdf74a2.ngrok.com/notify";
```

and also update on api console project.